# Ensure child container exits when parent does without using --interactive

Tags: docker

I am trying to run a container like this:

```bash
docker run
    --rm
    --init
    --tty
    --sig-proxy=true
    hasura/graphql-engine:v2.33.0
```

I am running this from a CLI I have built in which I am connecting stdout and stderr to files.

I want the container to exit when the parent exits. If I use `--interactive` it does this, but when I do so, it messes up my terminal and after the CLI exits, I have to use `stty sane` to fix it.

I was hoping that `--sig-proxy=true` would cause the signals to be passed through even without `--interactive`, but it doesn't work.

I have tried various combinations of these flags (with / without `--tty`, `--interactive`, etc). I'm fairly certain that `--init` isn't necessary because the process inside the container correctly handles signals it receives.

I have tried setting `--interactive` and setting stdin to /dev/null but then the container fails to start, I suppose because the whole point of `--interactive` is it is meant to connect to stdin. I've tried connecting it to a pipe but that doesn't work either (perhaps I need to open both ends of the pipe), it also fails to start. I have also tried using `--interactive` and connecting a random tty (`/dev/ttyq0`) to stdin. The container starts in this case but it never receives the signal from the parent.

I need some solution where the child (the container) stays connected to the parent (the CLI) so that the former exits when the latter does. How can I not connect stdin to my container while still ensuring it exits when the parent exits?

Comment: Docker doesn't have any concept of "parent" or "child" containers.  For your setup it might help that you've started the container with `--rm` (I hope, an SDK equivalent of this, like Python `autoremove=True`) which will remove the container if its process exits.  The most robust thing will be to clean up the container in an application shutdown hook or signal handler of some sort, but even this won't be 100% robust.

Comment: If I use --interactive the container I run with docker run shuts down when the calling process shuts down, so while it's not strictly a child in the forking sense, it works in effect because the signal seems to get propagated to the "child". There is no parent container here btw, there is only one container getting created by docker run from the CLI (the parent in this case). I agree some kind of signal handler in the CLI would be one way to make this work but given it's almost working save for the issue with the terminal getting messed up, I figure some combination of flags must be possible.

Comment: I just tried starting the container and attaching to it separately. Despite what the docs imply, I didn't find that the signal would be propagated through to the container.

Comment: Interesting, when I use another image like `postgres:14.9` even without `--interactive` the container shuts down properly when the parent shuts down.